# Datetime is not equal to itself in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I created a simple program to python that check if this X is expired.

```
import datetime

expired_on = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(0, 20) # add 20 seconds for expiration time

while True:
    X = datetime.datetime.now()
    if expired_on == X:
        print(f"this {X} is expired.")
        break
```

but it didn't break after 20 seconds.

Comment: The chance that `datatime().now()` is exactly equal to a predefined time is practically zero. Try something like `if X >= expired_on:` instead.

Comment: Wait. Your answer is actually right.

Comment: It's ok now guys.
I just forgot the logic behind the expirations lmao!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be much cleaner.

import datetime

```
expired_on = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)  # Add 20 seconds for expiration time

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if expired_on <= now:
        print('Expired.')
        break
```